# How to get exact path of servlet where it is running?

Tags: servlets, path

I have an application that I use in a servlet. The application assumes the text database residing in the same directory where it is being executed. When I am trying to use it in servlet and even after placing the text database files in /WebContent, /DataProject and also src folders. The application cannot find the database. I need to know exactly where the servlet file is being executed so I can place the database files in the same directory. I have already /.metadata/.plugin......../tmp0/wtpwebapps directory. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't do that. Configure an absolute path in your web.xml, and use this absolute path.

Comment: what  do you mean by text database

Comment: @Konza By text database I mean a directory of text files which is used as a database in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when  we access files in java we give the absolute path. Dont use the relative path. We use relative paths for jsp/html/css etc. For accessing normal files use the complete path. So put the files in /home/tomcat/.../../directoryDatabase